# FlipsideViewController not dismissing

Tags: ios, objective-c, view

My FlipsideViewController's "done" button is not working (no crash, but not dismissing the view either). Here's the code:

In FlipSideViewController.h

```
@class FlipsideViewController;

@protocol FlipsideViewControllerDelegate
- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(FlipsideViewController *)controller;
@end

@interface FlipsideViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

- (IBAction)done:(id)sender;

@end
```

In FlipSideViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender
{
// an NSLog statement that is here is logging properly
[self.delegate flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:self];

}
```

In MainViewController.h

```
@interface FifthViewController : UIViewController <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> 
...
```

In MainViewController.m

```
- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(FlipsideViewController *)controller
{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showAlternate"]) {
    [[segue destinationViewController] setDelegate:self];
}
}
```

By the way, this is a tabbed application, so I'm think that might have something to do with it. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: put nslog in `done:` , is it printing?

Comment: Did you set MainViewController to be the delegate of FlipsideViewController? Try putting a log inside the flipsideViewControllerDidFinish: method, and see if it prints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem. If you look in the question code, under MainViewController.m, it is imperative that you set the segue identifier in your storyboard file, as well as in code:

```
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showAlternate"]) {
[[segue destinationViewController] setDelegate:self];
}
```

Thank you, sergio, for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender
{
   // an NSLog statement that is here is logging properly
   [self.delegate performSelector:@selector(flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:)
            withObject:self
            afterDelay:0.0];
}
```

It happens sometime that the dismiss must be executed on the next iteration of the run loop. This is what the `performSelector` statement above accomplishes.

Comment: No luck. I changed my FlipsideViewController.h file to '@property (weak, nonatomic) NSObject <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> *delegate;' to get rid of the error message, but the view still didn't dismiss. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: I just checked- it is nil. Why?

Comment: possibly because of the "auto-zeroing" feature of `weak` properties. This would mean that your presenting controller has no owner and it is released, then weak properties are zeroed-in. So, you should check the way you instantiate your presenting view controller. paste some more code, please...

Comment: Changed: @property (strong, nonatomic) NSObject <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> *delegate; but self.delegate is still nil.

Comment: you see, there is something that it is not entirely clear to me... you are using segues, and displaying a modal view... are you sure that `[segue destinationViewController]` in `FifthController` and the FlipSideViewController are the same object? or is `FlipsideViewController` presented in other ways?

Comment: [segue destinationViewController] and FlipsideViewController are equivalent.

Comment: have you checked that with some `NSLog` trace? sorry to insist, but it is really strange... I would check that `[segue destinationViewController]` and `self` (done:) are the same...